# When is it necessary to protect both GET and POST versions of /Edit?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security

All my controllers have pairs of actions for `/Edit`, one for a GET request and one for a POST request. I already add permissions-checking (authorization) on the GET call to make sure nobody who shouldn't have access to an object, doesn't get in there.

Do I need to add the same check on the POST version of the method? Is it redundant, or should I reasonably expect someone to spoof the HTTP POST request even though they won't have access to the GET version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's [trivially easy](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/httpscripting.html) to send a POST request to a URL. If your site deals with sensitive/secret data, you should expect people to try all sorts of ways of getting at it, and you should make sure all access points (including POST requests) check that the user is authorized to access the request.

Answer (score 0):

You may not realize that you've stumbled upon what has been a major vulnerability for many sites in the past.  Often times, developers protect access to a page through GET requests, but fail to protect POST because they don't expect it to be used.  However many web frameworks have default settings to handle GETs and POSTs the same, by using either the GET query string or the POST parameters.  If yoru framework does this and you leave the default setting, you are wide open for attack.

It may also interest you to know that most web app pen-testers start by mapping the application, and making POST requests for GET resources and vice-versa.  You'd be shocked to know how many hacks are done this way.  Try making a POST request to Google and notice how they're service freaks out at you a bit.

In short, apply the same security code to both GET and POST requests!  If POST should never happen then disable it completely so your server returns an error.